# Cannot deploy grails on tomcat

Tags: grails, deployment, tomcat7, grails-2.1

When deploying a grails 2.1.1 war to tomcat7, I get the following errors:

```
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

Nov 19, 2012 9:17:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Nov 19, 2012 9:17:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/myapp] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 19, 2012 9:18:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deleteRedeployResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/myapp]
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Have you done something with logging?

Comment: Yeah, there was something messed up with the logging. I fixed it by going back to default grails logging settings. Now I get the same messages, without the 'log4j' error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335643/severe-errorlistener-start-deploying-grails-app-with-spring-security-ldap-pl/13346548#13346548)